# Cost Optimization Given Constraints

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, numerical-optimization

Balance = 1,360 USD

Cost = (0.0001% * Purchase Qty * Purchase Qty) + (1% * Purchase Qty)

Problem: Find maximum Purchase Qty while keeping Cost below Balance.

Is there a closed form solution to this?

Comment: The equation is $10^{-6}\cdot q^2+10^{-4}\cdot q=1360  $. Comprehensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the quantity be $q$.
$$1360=10^{-6} \cdot q^2$$
$$q^2=1.36 \cdot 10^9$$
$$q = \sqrt{1.36 \cdot 10^9}  \approx 3.688 \cdot 10^4$$